# Graphics in SAGE script

Tags: python, sage

I have the following piece of SAGE script:

```
...
 15 #ALGORYTHM
 16 N = 0;
 17 PointsList = []
 18 Dots = open("dots.dat", "wb")
 19 while( K < 1e10 ):
 20   T = 2.0/(1+K)
 21   A = Matrix([[T-1, 0],[T, 0]]) 
 22   B = Matrix([[0, 2-T],[0, 1-T]]) 
 23   while ( 1 ):
 24     U = A*U_p + B*U_pp
 25     N+=1
 26     if ( abs(U[0]) <= abs(U_p[1]) ):
 27       break
 28     U_pp = U_p
 29     U_p = U
 30   
 31   Dots.write( "%f %f\n" % (K, N) )
 32   PointsList.append((K, N))
 33   K*=2
 34   N=0
 35   U_pp = I_pp; U_p = I_p; U = I_U; 
 36 
 37 ShowPoints = list_plot( PointsList, color = 'red', size = 20 )
 38 show( ShowPoints )
 39 Dots.close()
 40 print Dots.closed
```

But after execution sage does not show me any picture and also no graphics displayed. My question is how to make SAGE draw if all commands are in script.
NOTE. I do not want to write my code in SAGE's command line.
Output is

```
wolfgang@wolfgang-IdeaPad-Z585:~/PyPrograms/Galperin_Variations$ sage 3_balls.sage 
Graphics object consisting of 1 graphics primitive
True
wolfgang@wolfgang-IdeaPad-Z585:~/PyPrograms/Galperin_Variations$
```

Comment: did you run this script ?

Comment: Yes.  sage Myscript.sage. Initially it was Myscript.py with line "from sage.all import *" and I run it sage -python Myscript.py

Comment: commands lines sometimes do some things automatically - for example Python Shell prints results of all commands but normally in script you have to use `print()`. Maybe you have to use some command to display it - like `show()`, `display()`, etc.

Comment: @furas I have edited my description of problem.

Comment: A workaround would be to save the plot: `ShowPoints.save('filename.png')`.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thank you. This solved **my** problem. But should I accept the solution?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to save the plot: `ShowPoints.save('filename.png')`.

Another (from a suggestion from William Stein): add the command `sleep(1)` to the end of your file and execute `echo "%attach 3_balls.sage" | sage -q` from the shell prompt. You can try it without the `sleep` command, but when Sage displays graphics, it does it by first saving the graphics to a temporary file, and when Sage exits, it deletes that file. So without the `sleep` command, the file might be deleted before it has a chance to open. Using `sage -q` instead of `sage` silences Sage's banner.

If I hear a better solution, I'll post it.